# The result of "request.getRemoteAddr()" is different in different browsers

Tags: tomcat

I'm learning JSP now.
I tried to test a very simple sample JSP file, there is one line code inside:
...
<%
...
out.println("Your IP Address is : " + request.getRemoteAddr());
...
%>
...

I checked this JSP file, it works well, gives me expected information.
But, only above code output is different in different browsers:

IE8/Google Chrome: the output is correct, for example, 192.168.214.161

But in Firefox/Opera: my locale ip address becomes to another one: 192.168.99.211.

I asked our network administrator, but no sure what this means, may be a mail server.

So, anybody can teach me why?
Besides, my working environment is: Client side: WinXP; Server side: Windws Server 2003 R2/Apache Tocmat 5.5.17, JRE1.5.0_15.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your browsers have different proxy settings.

Comment: Thank you,Zian Choy. But I checked "proxy" setting in IE and Firefox, it seems they are same.

Comment: I have to say, Zian Choy, you are right. The wrong ip address is actually my proxy server. Anyway, my firefox proxy setting looks has no difference with IE, but still does not work! I have to disable using proxy, then no problem. For opera, just setting proxy everything is correct. Thank you, Zian Choy.